# List of property in order to generate SSIS package?

Tags: c#, ssis

I generate SSIS package using c#, and find information i need on tutorial over internet, but how people know the list of property they need to set up ?

For example the lookup component need code like that

```
lookupDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("SqlCommand", sqlcmd);
```

How do you know the exact spelling for "SqlCommand" and that you need this property ? Can't find any documentation on Microsoft site.

Comment: How are you generating it through C#? Are you using an official SSIS SDK to do it? Isn't all of this stuff taken care of in the SDK classes?

Comment: hello i use the official SDK,all the stuff have been take care of but can't find any documentation on properties, i was wondering how people deal with it ( re-engineering existing package with reflection ? )

Comment: Is your question how do I find the API documentation for the SSIS libraries?

Comment: Oh I see..... SqlCommand is not a class property it's just an arbitrary string. Sorry can't help you there.

Comment: Could you use the SSIS designer to find out the names of properties? Then try it in the C# code.